# Failed to call constructor: TypeError: Converter is not a function

Tags: typescript, typescript1.6

**Problem**: The Actual Code that the following Sample Code represents will Compile Successfully, but upon testing in the Javascript Console, it does not.

```
export class Converter {
  fields: Array<Field>;

  constructor (djangoRestMeta: any, fieldFactoryFn: IFieldFactory) {
    this.fields = [];
    for (var fieldName in djangoRestMeta) {
      var fieldConfig = djangoRestMeta[fieldName];
      fieldConfig.name = fieldName;
      this.fields.push(DjangoRestConfig.factory(<IDjangoRestFieldOptions>fieldConfig, fieldFactoryFn));
    };
  }

  public convert() {
    var configObjects: Array<AngularFormly.IFieldConfigurationObject> = [];
    this.fields.forEach(function(field) {
      configObjects.push(field.getConfigurationObject());
    });
    return configObjects;
  };
}


export function DjangoRestFrameworkAdapter(djangoRestMeta: Array<IDjangoRestFieldOptions>, fieldFactoryFn?: IFieldFactory) {
  var converter = new Converter(djangoRestMeta, fieldFactoryFn);
  return converter.convert();
}
```

and the compiled code is:

```
var DjangoRestConfig_1 = require("./DjangoRestConfig");
var Converter = (function () {
    function Converter(djangoRestMeta, fieldFactoryFn) {
        this.fields = [];
        for (var fieldName in djangoRestMeta) {
            var fieldConfig = djangoRestMeta[fieldName];
            fieldConfig.name = fieldName;
            this.fields.push(DjangoRestConfig_1.DjangoRestConfig.factory(fieldConfig, fieldFactoryFn));
        }
        ;
    }
    Converter.prototype.convert = function () {
        var configObjects = [];
        this.fields.forEach(function (field) {
            configObjects.push(field.getConfigurationObject());
        });
        return configObjects;
    };
    ;
    return Converter;
})();
exports.Converter = Converter;
function DjangoRestFrameworkAdapter(djangoRestMeta, fieldFactoryFn) {
    var converter = new Converter(djangoRestMeta, fieldFactoryFn);
    return converter.convert();
}
exports.DjangoRestFrameworkAdapter = DjangoRestFrameworkAdapter;
```

the execution fails exactly on: `var converter = new Converter(...)` and I got this error:

> TypeError: Converter is not a function

As I see the compiled code is valid ES5 code and should work and I don't see the error here

For information: it's tested with Chrome v47.0.2526.80 (64-bit), running on MacOS El Capitain

Comment: I would check once again that the order of loading of your compiled files is correct. Is really `Converter` object defined when you call `new Converter`?

Comment: the order is correct, but I think one of the existing problems is related to `var c= require("...");`. PS check the generated code https://gist.github.com/benzid-wael/7c88e9d6dd68c4483943

Comment: it seems that it was the problem, I compiled my project with browserify, and it's solved